# Android NDK clang compiler error showing 'No such file or directory' on Windows

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to learn how to use c/c++ native code with android using ndk r21. I linked my C++ cmake file into my android project and the cpp shared libraries files where generated. However, I am getting a compiler error as follows:-

C/C++ Configuration Problem
                Toka | debug | x86
                Compiler exited with error code 1: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe -xc++ --target=i686-none-linux-android16 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -DTOKA_ARCHIVE_DIR=\"../docs/\" -DTOKA_BASE_DIR=\"../\" -DTOKA_DATABASE_DIR=\"../docs/database/\" -DTOKA_DEVELOPMENT_BUILD -DTOKA_PLUGIN_DIR=\"plugins/Debug/\" -DTOKA_SOURCE -DToka_EXPORTS -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -fexceptions -frtti /W3 -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info -fPIC -c -fpch-preprocess -v -dD -E
                Android (5900059 based on r365631c) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 207d7abc...

This is the part of the error that I can copy to the clipboard. The full error on one of the libraries is in the image below.

[Error Message(Cannot Copy it to the clip board)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfD9W.png)

I tried searching google for similar errors and found none. Some people said it maybe path length problem on windows. I copied my ndk directly under C:\ to get the shortest path possible but to no avail. I followed the guide on configuring cmake and ndk for android studio [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds) but still got the same error. I installed a later version of cmake I later learnt was useless as ndk comes with it own cmake installation. I installed older ndk r20 and r12b and the problem still did not go away. Infact, it seemed r12b did not support cmake. I do not know what to do anymore. I have been trying to solve this for 3 days. it seems this problem has an obvious solution that I am overlooking. Can someone please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Aside from a limit on the paths to individual files, Windows also has a limit on the length of a command (i.e. the entire invocation of clang++ above), which I believe is 8192 characters.

Comment: Also, don't post screenshots of error messages. Put the full text in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I could not copy it. it did not allow me to copy everything.

Comment: Post the sources. Without them it will be hard for anyone to figure out why this happens exactly.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a space character problem. Project folder (or project name) should not contain any white space character. Obviously some internal command line does not support while space, or some double quotes are missing.